# Select 2nd row in XML Column in database using SQL

Tags: sql, xml, database, xml-column

Having trouble selecting a specific info from an XML Format in a column of a table in the database. I need to pull the Success message for ModuleID 959

| SubmissionID | ModuleID | CreatedOn | XMLCOL | UpdatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 959 | 1-1-22 | "see XML below" | 1-1-22 |
| 26 | 339 | 2-1-22 | Null | 2-1-22 |

Below is the data inside the XML column within the database - what I want to achieve is to show the 2nd ResultType "success" in the query with SQL.

```
<ArrayOfActionResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ActionResult>
    <ResultType>Redirected to Payment</ResultType>
    <ActionName>Payment</ActionName>
    <ExecutionTime></ExecutionTime>
    <ConditionSet>
      <Conditions />
      <ExecuteCondition>Always</ExecuteCondition>
      <MatchCondition>All</MatchCondition>
      <ExecuteStatus>0</ExecuteStatus>
      <Groups />
    </ConditionSet>
    <ConditionsMet>true</ConditionsMet>
    <Condition />
  </ActionResult>
  <ActionResult>
    <ResultType>Success</ResultType>
     <ActionName>Payment</ActionName>
    <ExecutionTime></ExecutionTime>
    <ConditionSet>
      <Conditions />
      <ExecuteCondition>Always</ExecuteCondition>
      <MatchCondition>All</MatchCondition>
      <ExecuteStatus>0</ExecuteStatus>
      <Groups />
    </ConditionSet>
    <ConditionsMet>true</ConditionsMet>
  </ActionResult>
</ArrayOfActionResult>
```

Currently I'm trying to use the SQL below to no avail

```
SELECT [XMLCOL].value('/ArrayOfActionResult/ActionResult/ResultType[2]') as PaymentMessage
FROM Databasetable
where [ModuleID] = 959
```

Hopefully this makes sense, I found it quite difficult to explain, I am very new to SQL

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check it out below.

Assuming your db is MS SQL Server.

The XQuery `.value()` method has two mandatory parameters.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ModuleID INT PRIMARY KEY, XMLCOL XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (ModuleID, XMLCOL) VALUES
(959, N'<ArrayOfActionResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ActionResult>
        <ResultType>Redirected to Payment</ResultType>
        <ActionName>Payment</ActionName>
        <ExecutionTime></ExecutionTime>
        <ConditionSet>
            <Conditions/>
            <ExecuteCondition>Always</ExecuteCondition>
            <MatchCondition>All</MatchCondition>
            <ExecuteStatus>0</ExecuteStatus>
            <Groups/>
        </ConditionSet>
        <ConditionsMet>true</ConditionsMet>
        <Condition/>
    </ActionResult>
    <ActionResult>
        <ResultType>Success</ResultType>
        <ActionName>Payment</ActionName>
        <ExecutionTime></ExecutionTime>
        <ConditionSet>
            <Conditions/>
            <ExecuteCondition>Always</ExecuteCondition>
            <MatchCondition>All</MatchCondition>
            <ExecuteStatus>0</ExecuteStatus>
            <Groups/>
        </ConditionSet>
        <ConditionsMet>true</ConditionsMet>
    </ActionResult>
</ArrayOfActionResult>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT ModuleID
    , XMLCOL.value('(/ArrayOfActionResult/ActionResult[2]/ResultType/text())[1]','VARCHAR(30)') as PaymentMessage
FROM @tbl
WHERE ModuleID = 959;
```

**Output**

```
+----------+----------------+
| ModuleID | PaymentMessage |
+----------+----------------+
|      959 | Success        |
+----------+----------------+
```